# how to correct group by id column - sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, scale

I have this query:

```
SELECT TwI_TwIId,
       TwI_TwrId,
       TwI_MagId,
       SUM(TwI_Ilosc) AS Ilosc,
       SUM(TwI_Wartosc) AS Wartosc,
       SUM(TwI_Braki) AS Braki,
       SUM(TwI_Rezerwacje) AS Rezerwacje,
       SUM(TwI_Zamowienia) AS Zamowienia
FROM cdn.TwrIlosci
WHERE twi_magid = 1
GROUP BY TwI_TwrId,
         TwI_TwIId,
         TwI_MagId
ORDER BY TwI_TwIId;
```

I don't know why but this query can't scale duplicate TwI_TwrId.

I have this result:

[image: Look Here]

Comment: What does "can't scale duplicate TwI_TwrId" mean??

Comment: Add DDL and DLM statements, and your expected results. We can't run your SQL and we don't know what it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: remove TwI_TwIId in group by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `TwI_TwrId` has unique `TwI_TwIId` for each, you need to exclude them from `group by` clause :

```
SELECT TwI_TwrId, TwI_MagId,
       SUM(TwI_Ilosc) AS Ilosc,
       SUM(TwI_Wartosc) AS Wartosc,
       SUM(TwI_Braki) AS Braki,
       SUM(TwI_Rezerwacje) AS Rezerwacje,
       SUM(TwI_Zamowienia) AS Zamowienia
FROM cdn.TwrIlosci
WHERE twi_magid = 1
GROUP BY TwI_TwrId, TwI_MagId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is giving the distinct combination of the three columns TwI_TwrId,TwI_TwIId,TwI_MagId, If you want to remove the duplicate of TwI_TwrId then run the below one

```
SELECT 
       TwI_TwrId,
       TwI_MagId,
       SUM(TwI_Ilosc) AS Ilosc,
       SUM(TwI_Wartosc) AS Wartosc,
       SUM(TwI_Braki) AS Braki,
       SUM(TwI_Rezerwacje) AS Rezerwacje,
       SUM(TwI_Zamowienia) AS Zamowienia
FROM cdn.TwrIlosci
WHERE twi_magid = 1
GROUP BY TwI_TwrId,
         TwI_MagId
```